# Mac - Sublime Text and R

Tags: r, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am trying to write my first line in R using sublime text.

First I installed the SublimeREPL and enhance R packages. I edited the user settings to:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};~/Applications/R.app"},
    "show_transferred_text": true
}
```

Now I can launch REPL r without any trouble.
What I'd like to do know is to write some R code in one of my tabs and execute it automatically in the REPL r window. 
What is happening now is when I use the cmd+enter shortcut to execute my selected code, it is executed but in the R.app console not in my REPL [r] window in sublime.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: bring up the application menu panel and search for `R Application Switch`, then select `SublimeREPL`

Comment: thanks it worked! Feel free to add it as an answer so I can validate it

Comment: You should checkout the excellent RStudio IDE (http://www.rstudio.com/)

Comment: @Spearfisher I have done that but the problem is that the commands I send are not recorded in the REPL r command history. How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: Currently the functionality moved from R-Box to SendREPL (see 
README here: https://github.com/randy3k/SendREPL).

After installing SendREPL, you need to bring up the command palette and search for `SendREPL: Choose REPL Program`

---

You need to change Enhanced-R.sublime-settings (User) from

```
"osx":
{
    "App": "R"
},
```

to

```
"osx":
{
    "App": "SublimeREPL"
},
```

Which also can be done by bringing up command panel (`ctrl+shift+p` on linux/windows or `cmd+shift+p` on mac) and search for `R Application Switch` and then select `SublimeREPL`

Note that `Enhanced-R` has been deprecated. Use `R-Box`

Comment: I can't find anywhere R application switch.

Comment: @user4050 have u installed R-Box?

Comment: I have done all the above and it works, the issue I have is that the commands I send through sendREPL don't appear in the REPL r history